# importError: no module named components.panel

Tags: python

I have a folder called `python_udl`.

I've created there empty file called `__init__.py` and two files `ui.idl` and `ui_parser.py`. Also I created folder `components` in the same directory and put there `__init__.py` and `panel.py`.

In end my folder structure looks like this

```
python_udl\
    __init__.py
    ui.idl
    ui_parser.py
    components\
        __init__.py
        panel.py
```

File `ui_parser.py` parse `ui.idl` and create object from `panel.py` class.
`ui_parser.py` looks like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from components.panel import Panel

def parse_ui():
    file_data = open('ui.idl').read()
    xml_data = BeautifulSoup(file_data, 'html.parser')
    for element in xml_data.find_all('element'):
        if (element['type'] == 'panel'):
            make_panel(element.color.get_text(), element.position.get_text())
    def make_panel(color, position):
        p = Panel(color, position)
        print 'Formed [' + p.to_string() + '] object ';


parse_ui()
```

`panel.py` looks like this

```
class Panel:
    def __init__(self, color, position):
        self.color = color.split(',')
        self.position = position.split(',')
    def to_string(self):
        return 'Panel:<' + str(self.color) + ';' + str(self.position) + '>';
```

By when I try to run `ui_parser.py`

```
>python ui_parser.py
```

I've got an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ui_parser.py", line 2, in <module>
    from components.panel import Panel
ImportError: No module named components.panel
```

What's the problem?

Comment: try set components.panel in the pythonpath

Comment: But if I move it to another machine - I have to set again in that case.